# Como receber uma lista com cada datas entre duas datas em python

Tags: python

No ponto que estou agora, eu a preciso obter uma função que me retorne uma lista com todas as datas entre duas datas.

Não sei exatamente como fazer essa operação, se posso utilizar alguma biblioteca especifica como datetime e como usaria exatamente para obter esse resultado.

Estou usando datas no formato dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Mariano, edite sua pergunta e coloca exemplo do seu projeto, e o código do que você está tentando executar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando a biblioteca datetime

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

data_inicio = date(2021, 1, 1)
data_fim = date(2021, 2, 3)

delta = data_fim - data_inicio

lista_datas = []
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = data_inicio + timedelta(days=i)
    lista_datas.append(day)


print(lista_datas)
```

O resultado será

```
[datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 2), datetime.date(2021, 1, 3), datetime.date(2021, 1, 4), datetime.date(2021, 1, 5), datetime.date(2021, 1, 6), datetime.date(2021, 1, 7), datetime.date(2021, 1, 8), datetime.date(2021, 1, 9), datetime.date(2021, 1, 10), datetime.date(2021, 1, 11), datetime.date(2021, 1, 12), datetime.date(2021, 1, 13), datetime.date(2021, 1, 14), datetime.date(2021, 1, 15), datetime.date(2021, 1, 16), datetime.date(2021, 1, 17), datetime.date(2021, 1, 18), datetime.date(2021, 1, 19), datetime.date(2021, 1, 20), datetime.date(2021, 1, 21), datetime.date(2021, 1, 22), datetime.date(2021, 1, 23), datetime.date(2021, 1, 24), datetime.date(2021, 1, 25), datetime.date(2021, 1, 26), datetime.date(2021, 1, 27), datetime.date(2021, 1, 28), datetime.date(2021, 1, 29), datetime.date(2021, 1, 30), datetime.date(2021, 1, 31), datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), datetime.date(2021, 2, 2), datetime.date(2021, 2, 3)]
```

**Update - Como obter as datas no formato string**

```
from datetime import datetime

lista_datas_str = [datetime.strftime(dt, format="%d/%m/%Y") for dt in lista_datas]

print(lista_datas_str)
['01/01/2021', '02/01/2021', '03/01/2021', '04/01/2021', '05/01/2021', '06/01/2021', '07/01/2021', '08/01/2021', '09/01/2021', '10/01/2021', '11/01/2021', '12/01/2021', '13/01/2021', '14/01/2021', '15/01/2021', '16/01/2021', '17/01/2021', '18/01/2021', '19/01/2021', '20/01/2021', '21/01/2021', '22/01/2021', '23/01/2021', '24/01/2021', '25/01/2021', '26/01/2021', '27/01/2021', '28/01/2021', '29/01/2021', '30/01/2021', '31/01/2021', '01/02/2021', '02/02/2021', '03/02/2021']
```

**fim do update**

Espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Paulo Marques. Como posso transformar esta resposta em uma string com esse esquema: dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: @MarianoTupa, atualizei o post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime                                                                                                             
data = datetime.datetime(2014,7,16,23)
dataatual = datetime.datetime.now()                           
diff = dataatual - data
days = diff.days
anos, days = days // 365, days % 365                          
meses, days = days // 30, days % 30
seconds = diff.seconds
horas, seconds = seconds// 3600, seconds % 3600              
minutos, seconds = seconds // 60, seconds % 60                                                                              
print("Desde {} passaram {} anos, {} meses, {} dias, {} horas, {} minutos e {} segundos".format(data, anos, meses, days, horas, minutos, seconds))
```

Você precisa usar uma biblioteca pra pegar a hora atual, você pode fazer umas modificações neste códico também para o usuário poder digitar a data.

Answer (score 0):

A forma que consegui solucionar o problema foi assim, talvez não seja a melhor solução, mas funcionou para meu proposito.

```
def date_generator(self, data, data_final):

    data_dd = data[:2]
    data_dd = int(data_dd)

    data_mm = data[3:]
    data_mm = data_mm[:2]
    data_mm = int(data_mm)

    data_yy = data[6:]
    data_yy = int(data_yy)

    data_final_dd = data_final[:2]
    data_final_dd = int(data_final_dd)

    data_final_mm = data_final[3:]
    data_final_mm = data_final_mm[:2]
    data_final_mm = int(data_final_mm)

    data_final_yy = data_final[6:]
    data_final_yy = int(data_final_yy)


    data_inicio = date(data_yy, data_mm, data_dd)

    data_fim = date(data_final_yy, data_final_mm, data_final_dd)

    delta = data_fim - data_inicio

    lista_datas = []

    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        day = data_inicio + timedelta(days=i)
        lista_datas.append(day.strftime('%d/%m/%y'))

    return lista_datas
```

Comment: Tem um jeito bem mais fácil de transformar as strings em datas, com `strptime`. E em vez de criar um `timedelta` a cada iteração do `for`, outra alternativa é ir incrementando a data inicial em 1 dia, até que ela seja maior que a data final: https://ideone.com/JORLGI